# Help me identify the following insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This is my first post in this forum. I found the following insect at my kitchen in my apartment in Kolkata, India. Could you please help me identify the insect. 
Thank you. 
Best regards, 
Saugata

[image: photo of the insect]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might be a red palm weevil

Rhynchophorus ferrugineus

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhynchophorus

[image: enter link description here]